# python Convert numpy.ndarray from (4942L, 1L) to (4942L,)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two objects that need to be the same shape. One of them is (4942L, 1L) and other one is   (4942L,)
How can I convert the below first type of array to the second type?

```
#This is what I have:
(array([[0],
       [0],
       [0],
       ..., 
       [0],
       [0],
       [0]], dtype=int64),
 #This is what I need
array([0, 1, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1]))
```

Comment: try... a = np.zeros((5,1))… then ... a.squeeze() …. notice that '1' in shape is now gone if you do a.shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array is bound to the variable `array`, you can do this with `reshape`:

```
new_array = np.reshape(array, (len(array)))
```

Indexing also works:

```
new_array = array[:, 0]
```